# Two R plots with different scaling

Tags: r, maps

I want to plot two countries:

```
library('maps')

map(database='world',regions='germany')
map(database='world',regions='burkina faso')
```

But "burkina farso" is clipped by the x-region of "germany". 
How can I get a complete map of "burkina faso"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the default margin of `maps::map()` is set at `mar = c(4.1, 4.1, 4, 0.1)`.

You could reduce left and right margin area.

```
library('maps')

map(database='world',regions='germany')
map.axes(cex.axis=0.8)

dev.new()                                      # if you are using R-Gui
par(mar=c(3, 1, 2, 0) + 0.1)                   # margins in lines (bottom, left, top, right)
map(database='world',regions='burkina faso')
map.axes(cex.axis=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works. But I always have to use the `par(...)` again if I plot one more country, right?

Comment: @Red-Cloud I think so, yes.